# Can anyone recognise this type of encoding?

Tags: encryption, web-application, decryption

I'm doing some testing and I need help understanding this type of encoding, Any ideas? Can anyone recognise it?

b90de9b1-eab7-c579-ef74-08d2be5bc0ba

Thanks.

Comment: I'm learning an alien language and I want to understand this phrase: "A A AA AAAA AAAAAAA A AA AAA!"

Comment: Your question is likely never to have an answer.  That is why such questions have always been closed here.

Comment: It looks like an MD5 hash in hex.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) and not a type of encoding.  Stands for `Globally Unique Identifier` and has a number of potential uses depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it look like it.  I will add this to my report.